# O que significa ponto e vírgula após um "if"?

Tags: c, c++, if, sintaxe

Estava analisando um código e me deparei com um ponto e vírgula após um `if`, o que significa usar o ponto e vírgula após um `if`?

código:

```
int base_calc(int cb)
{
    if( cb < 30 ) {
        ;
    } else if( cb < 20 ) {
        cb = 30 - 1;
    } else {
        cb = 30;
    }

    return cb;
}
```

Comment: Comando nulo, não faz nada.

Comment: Pode ser um jeito de dizer que o bloco está propositalmente vazio (diferente de uma linha em branco que poderia sugerir esquecimento).

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3):

Não é após o `if`, o ponto e vírgula existe para encerrar um *statement*, igual você sempre usou em "final de linha" (que no fundo não encerra a linha, a gente fala isso informalmente, ele encerrar o comando), inclusive usou em outros pontos. Se o comando não tem nada ele encerra nada, sem problema algum (chama-se *empty statement*). Se fizer isto dá no mesmo:

```
int base_calc(int cb)
    if( cb < 30 ) {
    } else if( cb < 20 ) {
        cb = 30 - 1;
    } else {
        cb = 30;
    }
    return cb;
}
```

Foi usado aí para deixar mais claro no código que a intenção é criar um bloco que não faz nada. Note que esse meu código passa menos a ideia de que tem algo vazio a ser feito ali, não é o fim do mundo, mas você perde um tempinho pra ter certeza que é isso mesmo.

Dá para reescrever o código para não precisar disto. Em C ou C++ não se costuma muito fazer isto porque é menos eficiente, a reescrita costuma ser melhor (ainda que nem sempre seja necessário toda essa eficiência.

Só tome cuidado com as chaves aí. Isto não dá o mesmo resultado:

```
int base_calc(int cb)
    if( cb < 30 )
        ;
    else if( cb < 20 )
        cb = 30 - 1;
    else
        cb = 30;
    return cb;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/Terminator.cpp).

Neste caso o `;` está encerrando o *statement* `if` e nada mais pra frente será executado. Por sorte tem um `else if` em seguida, ele ele não pode estar solto então dará um erro de sintaxe na compilação.

Answer (score 1):

Ali só está dizendo que não tem nada. Colocar um `;` sem nenhuma expressão antes é como se não houvesse nada naquela linha.

Portanto,

```
if( cb < 30 ) {
    ;
}

// é a mesma coisa de
if( cb < 30 ) {

}
```

Alguns programadores fazem isso para indicar que devia ter algo ali, que será implementado ou simplesmente pularam essa condição e foram direto pro `else`. Não é uma boa prática fazer isso, pois é a mesma coisa de:

```
bool condicao = false;
if(condicao == true) {
    ;
} else {
    // ...
}
```